# React application Cannot find module '...\@emotion\css'

Tags: node.js, material-ui, babeljs, server-side-rendering, emotion

I have a react application, (implements SSR with a Node backend).  The application uses material ui and I have installed all the required @emotion packages per documentation. See my package.json below.   I have cleared out both the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file and rerun npm install.  I did this twice with same results both times.

The application builds fine but when I start the application I get the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge> npm run start

> teachlearnchallenge@0.1.0 start
> node server

C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:31
    throw e;
    ^

Error: C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\src\utilities\useClasses.js: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\src\utilities\@emotion\css'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-assets\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\worker\babel-core.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\worker\handle-message.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\worker-client.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\node.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\nodeWrapper.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\server\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at PluginPass.call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-assets\lib\index.js:80:21)
    at call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\traverse\src\visitors.ts:292:14)
    at NodePath._call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\traverse\src\path\context.ts:35:20)
    at NodePath.call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\traverse\src\path\context.ts:20:17)
    at NodePath.visit (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\traverse\src\path\context.ts:94:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue 
(Lines removed to save space)
    at evaluateSync (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\gensync\index.js:251:28)
    at fn (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\gensync\index.js:89:14)
    at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\src\errors\rewrite-stack-trace.ts:99:14)
    at Object.transformSync (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\core\src\transform.ts:66:52)
    at transformSync (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\worker\transform.js:94:33)
    at Function.call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\worker\handle-message.js:15:16)
    at LocalClient.call (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\worker-client.js:103:27)
    at LocalClient.transform (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\worker-client.js:40:16)
    at compile (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\hook.js:57:25)
    at compileBabel7 (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\@babel\register\src\hook.js:48:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:113:29)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:121:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\src\containers\/ContactContainer.jsx:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:117:24) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
Lines ommitted to save space.
  ]
}

Node.js v18.15.0
PS C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\teachlearnchallenge>
```

The @emotion\css is only used in the useClasses module which is below.  As the first line of the error indicates, it is the useClasses module that cannot find the @emotion\css package.  I have used the useClasses module in another application and it works fine.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/css';
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
//const css = require('@emotion/css');

const useClasses = stylesElement => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return useMemo(() => {
    const rawClasses = typeof stylesElement === 'function'
      ? stylesElement(theme)
      : stylesElement;
    const prepared = {};

    Object.entries(rawClasses).forEach(([key, value = {}]) => {
      prepared[key] = css(value);
    });

    return prepared;
  }, [stylesElement, theme]);
};

export default useClasses;
```

Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "teachlearnchallenge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
    "@emotion/css": "^11.11.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-assets": "^1.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^4.4.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.18",
    "material-react-table": "^1.14.0",
    "material-ui-confirm": "^3.0.9",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.2",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.10.15",
    "npm-outdated": "^0.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "socket-controllers": "^0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.15.0",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my Node server code as it might be that I need to add some plugins to the babel code but I am not sure what needs to be done.

```
'use strict';
require("dotenv").config();
require('@babel/register')({
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        'transform-assets',
        {
          extensions: ['css', 'svg'],
          name: 'static/media/[name].6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.[ext]',
        },
      ],
    ],
  });
  const React = require('react');
  const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
  const App = require('../src/App').default;
  const express = require('express');
 
  const path = require('path');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  const cors = require("cors");
  const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
  const roomRoutes = require("./routes/room");
  const messageRoutes = require("./routes/messages");

  const constructAssociationRoutes = require("./routes/constructAssociationRoutes");
  const constructCountingRoutes = require("./routes/constructCountingRoutes");
  const constructDefinitionRoutes = require("./routes/constructDefinitionRoutes");
  const constructEquationRoutes = require("./routes/constructEquationRoutes");
  const constructFactRoutes = require("./routes/constructFactRoutes");
  const constructMiniSegmentRoutes = require("./routes/constructMiniSegmentRoutes");
  const constructPrefixRoutes = require("./routes/constructPrefixRoutes");
  const constructQuestionRoutes = require("./routes/constructQuestionRoutes");
  const constructQuoteRoutes = require("./routes/constructQuoteRoutes");
  const constructSegmentRoutes = require("./routes/constructSegmentRoutes");
  const constructStatementRoutes = require("./routes/constructStatementRoutes");
  const constructSuffixRoutes = require("./routes/constructSuffixRoutes");
  const frameworkRecentlyViewedRoutes = require("./routes/frameworkRecentlyViewedRoutes");
  const frameworkTabularRoutes = require("./routes/frameworkTabularRoutes");
  const frameworkTicTacToeRoutes = require("./routes/frameworkTicTacToeRoutes");
  const frameworkTriviaRoutes = require("./routes/frameworkTriviaRoutes");
  const gamerPreferencesRoutes = require("./routes/gamerPreferencesRoutes");
  const gamerRankingRoutes = require("./routes/gamerRankingRoutes");
  const gamerResultRoutes = require("./routes/gamerResultRoutes");

  const socket = require("socket.io");

  const app = express();
  
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
  app.use("/api/room", roomRoutes);
  app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);

  app.use("/api/constructs/associations", constructAssociationRoutes);
  app.use("/api/constructs/countings", constructCountingRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/definitions", constructDefinitionRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/equations", constructEquationRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/facts", constructFactRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/miniSegments", constructMiniSegmentRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/prefixs", constructPrefixRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/questions", constructQuestionRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/quotes", constructQuoteRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/segments", constructSegmentRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/statements", constructStatementRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/constructs/suffixs", constructSuffixRoutes); 

  app.use("/api/frameworks/recentlyViewed", frameworkRecentlyViewedRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/frameworks/tabulars", frameworkTabularRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/frameworks/ticTacToes", frameworkTicTacToeRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/frameworks/trivias", frameworkTriviaRoutes); 
  
  app.use("/api/games/preferences", gamerPreferencesRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/games/ranking", gamerRankingRoutes); 
  app.use("/api/games/results", gamerResultRoutes); 


  // Connection URL
  console.log("Index - process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URL = ", process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URL)
  mongoose
  .connect(process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    //serverApi: "ServerApiVersion.v1"
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB Connetion Successfull");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref){
    console.log("index - after mongoDB.connection.on('open', function())");
    
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
          setTimeout(function(){ 
            console.log("index - after mongoDB connection - list collection 1 names = ", names);
            if (err) {
              console.log("index - after mongoDB connection - list collection error = ", err);
            } else {
              console.log("index - after mongoDB connection - list collection 2 names = ", names);
            }                
          }, 1500);
        });
      }, 1500);

  });


  app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request URL = ${req.url}`);
    if (req.url !== '/') {
      return next();
    }
    //const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(React.createElement(App));
    //const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(App));
    //const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToReadableStream(React.createElement(App));
    const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToPipeableStream(React.createElement(App));
    //const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App));
    console.log(reactApp);
    
    const indexFile = path.resolve('build/index.html');
    fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error inside file read of index file, build/index.html")
        const errMsg = `There is an error: ${err}`;
        console.error(errMsg);
        return res.status(500).send(errMsg);
      }
  
      return res.send(
        data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${reactApp}</div>`)
      );
    });
  });
  
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));
  
  const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log('Express server is running on server:',process.env.PORT)
  );
  
  //const OriginURL = "http://localhost:3000";
  //origin: [process.env.SocketOriginURL_Dev],
  //origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
  //origin: ["https://teachlearnchallenge.com.herokuapp.com/"],
  const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
      //origin: ["https://teachlearnchallenge.com.herokuapp.com/"],
      origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
      credentials: true,
    },
  });
  
  //let users = [];
  //const messages = {
  //  general: [],
  //  random: [],
  //  jokes: [],
  //  javascript: []
  //};

 const onlineUsers = new Map();
 const onlineSockets = new Map();

 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Server - Connect - you are connected with socket");
  global.chatSocket = socket;
  socket.on("add-user", (userId, userName) => {
    onlineUsers.set(userId, {socket:socket.id, UserName: userName});
    onlineSockets.set(socket.id, {userId:userId, UserName: userName});
    //console.log("Server-Index-add-user to connection - onlineUsers = ", onlineUsers);
    //console.log("Server-Index-add-user to connection - onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
  });

  socket.on("join-room", (senderSocketID, userId, roomName) => {
    console.log("Server-Index Start - join-room - roomName = ", roomName);
    console.log("Server-Index Start - join-room - userId = ", userId);
    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log("Server-Index End -join-room")
    const connectedSockets = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName);
    let usersInRoom = [];
    if (connectedSockets)
    {
      console.log("Server-Index End - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
      let connectedSocketsArray = Array.from(connectedSockets);
      console.log("Server-Index End - connectedSocketsArray = ", connectedSocketsArray);

      for (let i=0; i<connectedSocketsArray.length; i++)
      {
        console.log("Server-Index End - connectedSocketsArray[i] = ", connectedSocketsArray[i]);
        console.log("Server-Index End - onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
        let userInfo = onlineSockets.get(connectedSocketsArray[i]);
        console.log("Server-Index End - userInfo = ", userInfo);
        if (userInfo)
        {
          usersInRoom.push(userInfo);
        }
      }
      console.log("Server-Index End - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
    }
    console.log("Server-Index End - online-Users-InRoom - usersInRoom = ", usersInRoom);
    // to individual socketid (sender)
    console.log("Server-Index End - room-joined-sender");
    io.to(senderSocketID).emit("room-joined-sender", usersInRoom);
    // to all clients in the room except the sender
    console.log("Server-Index End - room-joined-othersNotSender");
    socket.to(roomName).emit("room-joined-othersNotSender", usersInRoom);

    // to all clients in the room including sender
    //io.in(roomName).emit("online-Users-InRoom", usersInRoom);    
  });

  
socket.on("leave-room",(roomName) => {  
  try{
    console.log("Server-leave-room - roomName =", roomName);
    socket.leave(roomName);
    const connectedSockets = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName);
    let usersInRoom = [];
    if (connectedSockets)
    {
      console.log("Server-leave-room - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
      let connectedSocketsArray = Array.from(connectedSockets);
      console.log("Server-leave-room - connectedSocketsArray = ", connectedSocketsArray);
  
      for (let i=0; i<connectedSocketsArray.length; i++)
      {
        console.log("Server-leave-room - connectedSocketsArray[i] = ", connectedSocketsArray[i]);
        console.log("Server-leave-room - onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
        let userInfo = onlineSockets.get(connectedSocketsArray[i]);
        console.log("Server-leave-room - userInfo = ", userInfo);
        if (userInfo)
        {
          usersInRoom.push(userInfo);
        }
      }
      console.log("Server-leave-room - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
    }

    console.log("Server-leave-room - usersInRoom = ", usersInRoom);
    // to all clients in the room
    io.in(roomName).emit("user-left-room-otherUsers", usersInRoom);
         
  }catch(e){
    console.log('[error]','leave-room :', e);
    socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
  }
})

socket.on("join-challenge", (senderSocketID, userId, challengeName) => {
  console.log("Server-Index Start - join-challenge - challengeName = ", challengeName);
  console.log("Server-Index Start - join-challenge - userId = ", userId);
  socket.join(challengeName);
  console.log("Server-Index Start - join-challenge - senderSocketID = ", senderSocketID);
  console.log("Server-Index -join-challenge")
  const connectedSockets = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(challengeName);
  let usersInChallenge = [];
  if (connectedSockets)
  {
    console.log("Server-Index - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
    let connectedSocketsArray = Array.from(connectedSockets);
    console.log("Server-Index - connectedSocketsArray = ", connectedSocketsArray);
    
    for (let i=0; i<connectedSocketsArray.length; i++)
    {
      console.log("Server-Index - connectedSocketsArray[i] = ", connectedSocketsArray[i]);
      console.log("Server-Index - onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
      let userInfo = onlineSockets.get(connectedSocketsArray[i]);
      console.log("Server-Index - userInfo = ", userInfo);
      if (userInfo)
      {
        usersInChallenge.push(userInfo);
      }
    }
    console.log("Server-Index - connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
  }

  console.log("Server-Index - users-InChallenge - usersInChallenge = ", usersInChallenge);
  // to individual socketid (private message)
  console.log("Server-Index - challenge-joined-sender");
  io.to(senderSocketID).emit("challenge-joined-sender", usersInChallenge);
  // to all clients in room1 except the sender
  console.log("Server-Index - challenge-joined-notSender");
  socket.to(challengeName).emit("challenge-joined-notSender", usersInChallenge);
  // to all clients in the room
  // io.in(challengeName).emit("users-InChallenge", usersInChallenge);
});

socket.on("start-challenge",(challengeName,opponent) => {  
  try{
    console.log('start-challenge - challengeName = ', challengeName);
    console.log('start-challenge - opponent = ', opponent);
    // to all clients in the room including sender
    io.in(challengeName).emit('challenge-started',opponent);
  }catch(e){
    console.log('[error]','error-challenge :', e);
    socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
  }
})

  socket.on("exit-challenge", (senderSocketID, userId, challengeName, playerNumber) => { 
    console.log('Server - exit-challenge -senderSocketID = ', senderSocketID);
    console.log('Server - exit-challenge -userId = ', userId);
    console.log('Server - exit-challenge -challengeName = ', challengeName);
    console.log('Server - exit-challenge -playerNumber = ', playerNumber); 
    try{
      console.log('Server - exit-challenge - Inside Try block{} ');
      console.log('Server - exit-challenge -challengeName = ', challengeName);
      if (playerNumber >=  1)
      {
        // if a player quits then, GAME OVER
        // Remove all sockets from Room after letting room members know that game is over
        console.log("Server-Index - challenge-exited-challengeOver");
        // to all clients in the room except sender
        socket.to(challengeName).emit('challenge-exited-challengeOver');  
        // remove all sockets from a room
        // The short method should work with version v4 or greater
        io.in(challengeName).socketsLeave(challengeName);
        //io.sockets.clients(challengeName).forEach(function(s){
        //  s.leave(challengeName);
        //});
        console.log("Server-Index - challenge-exited-sender");
        // to individual socketid (private message)
        io.to(senderSocketID).emit("challenge-exited-sender");
      } else
      {
        // Remove any observer but keep room and continue GAME
        socket.leave(challengeName);
      
        console.log('Server - exit-challenge - After user is removed (leave) room ');
        const connectedSockets = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(challengeName);
        console.log("Server-exit-challenge - 1 connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
        let usersInChallenge = [];

        if (connectedSockets)
        {
         let connectedSocketsArray = Array.from(connectedSockets);
          console.log("Server-exit-challenge - connectedSocketsArray = ", connectedSocketsArray);

          for (let i=0; i<connectedSocketsArray.length; i++)
          {
            console.log("Server-exit-challenge - connectedSocketsArray[i] = ", connectedSocketsArray[i]);
            console.log("Server-exit-challenge - onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
            let userInfo = onlineSockets.get(connectedSocketsArray[i]);
            console.log("Server-exit-challenge - userInfo = ", userInfo);
            if (userInfo)
            {
              usersInChallenge.push(userInfo);
            }
          }
          console.log("Server-exit-challenge - 2 connectedSockets = ", connectedSockets);
       } 
        console.log("Server-exit-challenge - usersInChallenge = ", usersInChallenge);
        console.log("Server-Index - challenge-exited-sender");
        // to individual socketid (private message)
        io.to(senderSocketID).emit("challenge-exited-sender");
        console.log("Server-Index - challenge-exited-challengeContinues"); 
        // to all clients in the room except sender
        socket.to(challengeName).emit('challenge-exited-challengeContinues', usersInChallenge);
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log('[error]','error-challenge :', e);
      socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
    }
  })

  socket.on("update-challenge",
    ( challengeName, 
      playerTurn, 
      opponent, 
      boardLayout) => {  
    try{
      console.log('update-challenge - challengeName = ', challengeName);
      console.log('update-challenge - playerTurn = ', playerTurn);
      console.log('update-challenge - opponent = ', opponent);
      console.log('update-challenge - boardLayout = ', boardLayout);
      let nextPlayerTurn = 1;
      if (opponent === "Real Person")
      {
        if (playerTurn === 1)
        {
          nextPlayerTurn = 2;
        }
      }
      console.log('update-challenge - nextPlayerTurn = ', nextPlayerTurn);
      socket.to(challengeName).emit('challenge-updated', 
                                    challengeName, 
                                    nextPlayerTurn, 
                                    opponent, 
                                    boardLayout);
      }catch(error){
      console.log('[error]','update challenge - error = ', error);
      socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
    }
  })

  socket.on("reset-challenge",(challengeName,boardLayout) => {  
    try{
      console.log('reset-challenge - challengeName = ', challengeName);
      console.log('reset-challenge - boardLayout = ', boardLayout);
      // to all clients in the room except sender
      socket.to(challengeName).emit('challenge-reset',challengeName,boardLayout);
    }catch(e){
      console.log('[error]','error-challenge :', e);
      socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
    }
  })

  socket.on("end-challenge",(challengeName,endingText,boardLayout) => {  
    try{
      console.log('end-challenge - challengeName = ', challengeName);
      console.log('end-challenge - endingText = ', endingText);
      console.log('end-challenge - boardLayout = ', boardLayout);
      // to all clients in the room except sender
      socket.to(challengeName).emit('challenge-ended',challengeName,endingText,boardLayout);
    }catch(e){
      console.log('[error]','error-challenge :', e);
      socket.emit('error','couldnt perform requested action');
    }
  })

  /* This version of send message is not currently being used. 
  socket.on("send message", ({content, to, sender, chatName, isChannel}) => {
    if (isChannel) {
      const payload = {
        content,
        chatName,
        sender,
      };
      socket.to(to).emit("new message", payload);
      console.log("Server-Index-send Message")
    } else {
      const payload = {
        content,
        chatName: sender,
        sender
      };
      socket.to(to).emit("new message", payload);
      console.log("Server-Index-new Message")
    }  
    if (messages[chatName]) {
      messages[chatName.push] ({
        sender,
        content
      });
    }
  });
  */
  //socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  //  users = users.filter(u => u.id !== socket.id);
  //  io.emit("new user", users);
  //  console.log("Server-Index-disconnect")
  //})

  socket.on("send-msg", (data, room, audience) => {
    // audience = "contact only" or "room" or "all users"
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- onlineUsers = ", onlineUsers);
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- onlineSockets = ", onlineSockets);
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- room = ", room);
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- audience = ", audience);
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- data.to = ", data.to[0]);
    console.log("Server-Index-send-msg- data.from = ", data.from);
    if (audience === "room" && room !== undefined & room !== null && room !== "")
    {
      socket.to(room).emit("msg-receive", data.msg, data.fromName);
      console.log (`The message ${data.msg} has been sent to Room contacts in room: ${room}`);
    } else if (audience === "all users")
    {
      const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to[0]);
      if (sendUserSocket) {
        socket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-receive", data.msg, data.fromName);
        console.log("Server-Index-message Received- onlineUsers = ", onlineUsers);
      }
    } else 
    {
      const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to[0]);
      if (sendUserSocket) {
        socket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-receive", data.msg, data.fromName);
        console.log("Server-Index-message Received")
      }
      console.log("Server-Index-send-msg - onlineUsers = ", onlineUsers);
      console.log (`The message ${data.msg} has been sent to contact: ${sendUserSocket}`);
    }
  });
});
```

The application builds with the npm run build command but when I run npm run start I get the error indicated above.

Appreciate any thoughts on what might be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

In researching this issue I found the Emotion site: https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop.  I believe that this would have solved my issue except that there are special considerations when using SSR.  Seems that there is a problem using the react-scripts to build an application that includes emotion and SSR.  There is another site that seems to cover this, https://emotion.sh/docs/ssr.  As I was having other problems using the react-scripts, I decided to go in a different direction.  I created a seperate build script for the server and client using Webpack.  I have included the Webpack server config file below.  The client Webpack config is similar with some changes for parameters like output, etc.  I have also included the package.json to show the scripts and packages included.  Once all was in place I was able to build and run the application with the three commands:

```
npm run build:server
npm run build:client
npm run start:server
```

webpack.server.js

```
const path = require ('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("interpolate-html-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode:'development',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "server/index.js"),
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.join(__dirname , 'build'), //Webpack may require /dist/
        filename: "server.bundle.js", // webpack may require bundle.js
        //libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
            }),
        //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),  
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
          }),
          new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
            PUBLIC_URL: 'static' // can modify `static` to another name or get it from `process`
        }),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
            raw: true,
            entryOnly: false
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, // matches .js, .jsx, files
                //test: /\.(jt|sx)$/, // matches .js, .ts, .jsx, .tsx files
                use: {  loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env",    
                                        ["@babel/preset-react", 
                                            {"runtime": "automatic"}
                                        ]
                                     ], 
                                    } 
                     }, 
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                //exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                //exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|gif|jpg|png)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg/,
                type: 'asset/inline'
            },
        ]
    },
    // pass all js files through Babel
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".*", ".js", ".jsx"],    // <-- added `.jsx` here
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "teachlearnchallenge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
    "@emotion/css": "^11.11.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.19",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.29.19",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-assets": "^1.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^4.4.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "formidable": "^3.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.18",
    "material-react-table": "^1.14.0",
    "material-ui-confirm": "^3.0.9",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.2",
    "node-gyp": "^9.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.10.15",
    "npm-outdated": "^0.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "socket-controllers": "^0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/server.bundle.js --max-old-space-size=8192",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.client.js & webpack --config webpack.server.js",
    "build:start": "webpack --config webpack.client.js && webpack --config webpack.server.js && node build/server.bundle.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "nodemon server",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "serve": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build:server": "webpack --config ./webpack.server.js",
    "build:client": "webpack --config ./webpack.client.js",
    "start:server": "node build/server.bundle.js",
    "start_OLD": "node server",
    "build_OLD": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.15.0",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.22.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "interpolate-html-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(axios|react-toastify))"
  ]
}
```